# What does passing msg.sender to an interface do?

Tags: contract-design, interfaces

I was doing Ethernaut's [Elevator](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xaB4F3F2644060b2D960b0d88F0a42d1D27484687) problem when I noticed the code below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface Building {
  function isLastFloor(uint) external returns (bool);
}


contract Elevator {
  bool public top;
  uint public floor;

  function goTo(uint _floor) public {
    Building building = Building(msg.sender);

    if (! building.isLastFloor(_floor)) {
      floor = _floor;
      top = building.isLastFloor(floor);
    }
  }
}
```

According to [the Solidity doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html?highlight=interface#interfaces), interfaces "cannot declare a constructor." But in the code above, in `Elevator` contract's `goTo` function, `msg.sender` is passed to the `Building` interface.

What does this do exactly if the interface does not have any constructor to accept arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the Solidity doc, interfaces "cannot declare a
> constructor." But in the code above, in Elevator contract's goTo
> function, msg.sender is passed to the Building interface.

Do not confuse a type cast `Building(msg.sender)` with a constructor call `new Building(msg.sender)`.

The former just allow to handle `msg.sender` as a type `Building` which according to the interface definition should implement a function `isLastFloor(uint) external returns (bool)`.

The latter would try to instantiate a new `Building`, but since it's impossible as you stated, it's just an invalid declaration.

> What does this do exactly if the interface does not have any
> constructor to accept arguments?

It's just interpreting `msg.sender` as a type `Building`, no constructor is involved, it's just a type casting.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now it makes much more sense. Just one question, msg.sender is a contract, does it mean that contract has to be defined as `contract Example is Building` , or as long as the `isLastFloor` function is implemented, then it should be fine?

Comment: As long as the `isLastFloor` function is implemented, it's fine, as it would mean that the `Building` interface is fully implemented.