# Is it not necessary to use deployed contract for using interface?

Tags: solidity, interfaces, msg.sender

I've been practicing Ethernaut Elevator problem. In this code, it just passing `msg.sender` to Building interface. But, I think that it should be passing deployed contract address of Building to use interface. Is it not necessary to use deployed contract for using interface?

I found answer about msg.sender with interface in the below link, that says `It's just interpreting msg.sender as a type Building, no constructor is involved, it's just a type casting.` But I don't really get it why interpret msg.sender as a type Building.

[What does passing msg.sender to an interface do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123370/what-does-passing-msg-sender-to-an-interface-do)

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface Building {
  function isLastFloor(uint) external returns (bool);
}


contract Elevator {
  bool public top;
  uint public floor;

  function goTo(uint _floor) public {
    Building building = Building(msg.sender);

    if (! building.isLastFloor(_floor)) {
      floor = _floor;
      top = building.isLastFloor(floor);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First more information on msg.sender

You can't pass `msg.sender` is always the address calls the function. If another contract calls this function then `msg.sender` is that contract, if a EOA (Externally Owned Account, aka an address owned by a person) calls this function then `msg.sender` is the user's address.
If you want to retrieve the first transaction sender then you should use `tx.origin` this will always return first EOA that starts the transaction.

#### Now we can analyse this contract.

```
interface Building {
  function isLastFloor(uint) external returns (bool);
}
```

This is the interface as you said so this should be a deployed contract.

```
Building building = Building(msg.sender);
```

They, assume this contract is called by a Building contract. If an EOA calls this function, it will revert since `building.isLastFloor(_floor)` will fail. So, it will work as:

EOA (user) calls Building contract Building contract makes an External call to Elevator contract so, msg.sender in Elevator contract becomes the Building contract.